# When do we use AnyObject in Swift?

Tags: swift

I learn Swift and I can't understand following example:

```
let jsonObject: [AnyObject] = [["name": "John", "age": 21],["name": "Bob", "age": 35]]
```

The `jsonObject` represents list of Dictionaries where `Dictionary` has structure `<key>,<value>`

Why I can define all of this as `AnyObject`?

From sources `AnyObject` is only empty`protocol`:

```
protocol AnyObject {}
```

---

I try to convert Object to Json String by using this method:

```
func JSONStringify(jsonObj: AnyObject) -> String {
    var e: NSError?
    let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
        jsonObj,
        options: NSJSONWritingOptions(0),
        error: &e)
    if e != nil {
        return ""
    } else {
        return NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
}


let jsonString = JSONStringify(jsonObject)
println(jsonString)
```

### ----------------------------

And what about `let jsonObject2: [String:AnyObject]`? As I understand the `String` inherits `AnyObject`. What does it mean?

### ----------------------------

In other example:

I created dummy class:

```
class Person {    
    var age:Int?    
    init(age:Int){
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

An and following code works too:

```
let jsonObject3: [AnyObject] = [
    ["name": "John", "person": Person(age: 12)],
    ["name": "Bob", "person": Person(age: 25)]
]
```

It not surprise me that `JSONStringify` method will not work  for `jsonObject3` because one of values is `Person` class. Hmm. Do I need to inherit `AnyObject` for `Person`?

Can somebody spread a light on `AnyObject` goal?

Thanks,

Comment: in general you are using `AnyObject` when you don't know / don't care which the exact type is. if you have some _ObjC_ background then I would say the `id` is the same thing on _ObjC_.

Comment: @holex if so, what `[String:AnyObject]` means?

Comment: that means your `Dictionary` has definite `String` keys, but the values for the keys can be _any_ types, like `Array`, `String` (etc...) or even your custom class in the same `Dictionary`. if you have `[String:Int]` that would mean the values must be `Int` type only, and nothing else in that particular `Dictionary`.

Comment: @holex `AnyObject` can not be used the same as in `Objective-C` because `String`, `Array` and `Dictionary` are not objects in Swift but `NSString`, `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` are in `Objective-C`. From a comment: "but the values for the keys can be any types, like Array, String." No they can't, they are not objects, they are structs. A `String` is not an `AnyObject`, neither is an `Array` or `Dictionary` an `AnyObject`.

Comment: @Zaph, I'd argue with you about why what you has said makes no sense, but I don't want to off the thread, because I did such long conversation before without brighting any light – but you can try to downcast them to `AnyObject` it will be successful every time as long as _downcasting `String` (or `Array<AnyObject>`) to `AnyObject` always succeeds_.

Comment: @holex: Try not importing Foundation and it will *never* "succeed".

Comment: @newacct, yes, that is true... and if I'm trying to use the `AnyObject` in _TeX_, it won't work either... and if you cut a man's leg off, he probably will _never_ scratch his toe again – so, what is the point of you are saying?

Comment: @holex: The point is that `AnyObject` is only for objects. `Array`, `Dictionary`, `String`, etc. are structs, not objects, and are not compatible with `AnyObject` in native Swift, in contrast with what you are saying. `Foundation` implements extensions to those types with bridging methods, allowing them to be implicitly converted to certain Cocoa objects, when `Foundation` is imported.

Comment: @newacct, my bad, I rephrase my question: what can you do with _Swift_ without `Foundation` or / and `UIKit`? briefly, you can do nothing. so, what you are saying is nice topic for a theoretical debate (not in this forum), but when you are in a commercial environment in practice, you cannot live without `Foundation` or / and `UIKit` – and debating about the _what-if_ theoretical situations are pointless at all – it would off the thread and confuses newbies, because they don't live in isolated environment.

Comment: @holex: That's like saying there's no point to learning C++ on Windows without the Windows API libraries, otherwise it would be "theoretical what-if situations". Of course not. Programming is not only for making UIs in "commercial environments". The Swift standard library and Darwin standard library contains more than enough things to make anything you need.

Comment: @holex: Also, I am responding to the fact that what you said is FACTUALLY WRONG. You said "the values for the keys can be any types", but they cannot be "any" types because if you make a custom struct or enum, it will not work.

Comment: @newacct, you are talking about now something totally different: _APIs / SKDs_ vs. _languages' syntaxes and types_. please do not mix them, because they are not the same at all. one is built on the other.